# Lookup Column missing columns

Tags: lookup-column

I was trying to make a lookup column in share point but not all of the columns were available for me to choose. Is there a way to expand the number of columns to choose from? Below is a picture of the lookup column settings I am trying to use.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lookup column has limitations and it support only below types

1. Single Line text
2. Number
3. Date
4. Date and time
5. Calculated single line text
6. External Data

For more information - http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2012/01/sharepoint-not-all-column-types-can-be.html?m=1